# Electron Frameless

Tags: electron

I would like to remove only some options from the frame, such as file, edit, view, etc. I would like to use only the minimize, maximize and close options.

It is possible?

[image: Electron Frameless]

Answer (score 0):

Use electron's BrowserWindow function [win.removeMenu()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winremovemenu-linux-windows) to remove application menus.

For your requirement, you shouldn't set 'frame:false' as you want the default title bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `win.setMenu(null)` to remove the menu options.